# Bounded Integral of ReLU/Positive Affine Transform

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, definite-integrals, machine-learning

I am looking to understand the integrals of rectified linear transforms in the context of machine learning: $f(x) = \begin{cases} \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+ 
b , \mathrm{if} \space \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} + 
 b \geq 0 \\
0, \mathrm{else} \end{cases}$.

In particular, I am interested in area integrals of that function when restricted to bounded domains. For example, let $B=[-1,1]^d$ and $\mathbf{w}, b$ be an arbitrary vector and scalar respectively.

Can the following integral be written in iterative or closed form: 
$\int_B\mathbb{I}_{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} + b \geq 0} \mathbf{dx}$? Although the result is polynomial in $\mathbf{w},b$, I have not been able to easily compute it for the general case.

I would also be interested in the following integrals: $\int_Bf(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{dx}$, $\int_B \mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{dx}$, $\int_B f^2(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{dx}$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems that this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07768.pdf might be of use for solving the principal integral as well as the first of the later integrals. Some more work will likely be needed to resolve the latter two, however.